# How can i increase file upload size of Jetty Servlet container?

Tags: file-upload, jetty

It seems that running Archiva using Jetty is limiting me to of file upload.

How do i increase file upload size of Jetty 6 Servlet container?

> the request was rejected because its size (34274761) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this can be done in Archiva:

> The maximum size of the file that can be uploaded is 10M by default.
>   To alter the setting, change struts.multipart.maxSize in the file
>   WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties in the Archiva web application
>   (located under apps/archiva in the standalone distribution).

Comment: http://www.skilledmonster.com/apache/archiva/apache-archiva-upload-artifact-error-upload-request-rejected-due-to-size-limitation/